# overriding RequriedFieldValidator on client side?

Tags: asp.net, .net, requiredfieldvalidator

Is it possible to override RequiredFieldValidator's functionality on client side ? I want to enhance it and use for all controls in page. Please guide.

Comment: Just to clarify, you would like just one RequiredFieldValidator to check ALL of the controls in a page?

Comment: @rikitikitik, no I just want it to work individually with controls. But I want to do it from client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you have to create a class that inherits from `RequiredFieldValidator` an create instances of this custom server control and add to your page. Actually, I think you could loop in all controls and change your modifications, something like this:

```
foreach(Control control in Page.Controls)
{
   if (control is RequiredFieldValidator)
   {
      RequiredFieldValidator rfv = (RequiredFieldValidator) control;
      // do your customizations for all RequiredFieldValidator
      rfv.ErrorMessage = "...";
      rfv.SetFocusOnError = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a client side way

Comment: thanks, but it will work on server side not on client side ? HOw to make this work on client side ?

Comment: `RequiredFieldValidator` is a server control, so it runs on server side generating a client side code (javascript and html). If you do any changes in server side it will change the generated client side code. I do not understand why you want to inherit on client side. I think it is not possible.